# Iterating through a string with sstream

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream

Here is a piece of code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  stringstream ss;
  string st = "2,3,55,33,1124,34";
  int a;
  char ch;
  ss.str(st);
  while(ss >> a)
  {
    cout << a << endl;
    ss >> ch;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It produces the output:

```
2
3
55
33
1124
34
```

But if I remove the line `ss >> ch` it produces the output: `2`.

Why does it stop iterating through the string? And what difference does `ss >> ch` make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What difference does `ss >> ch` make?

`ss >> ch` takes a character from your stream an store it in your `char ch` variable.

**So here it removes each and every comma (`,`) from your string.**

---

> Why does it stop iterating through the string without `ss >> ch`?

**Without this operation, your iteration stops because `ss >> a` fails, since it tries to store a comma inside `a`, an `int` variable.**

---

*Note:* If you replace your commas with spaces, you could get rid of `ss >> ch`, since a space is recognized as a separator.

Example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  stringstream ss;
  string st = "2 3 55 33 1124 34";
  int a;
  ss.str(st);
  while (ss >> a)
    cout << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why only comas though?

Comment: @weens Commas are not integers, so `ss >> a`, won't remove them. `ss >> ch`, will remove every character though

Comment: @weens Because in your case, the string contains commas. If you replace a comma by a letter, or any other non-separator character,  `ss>>ch;` will store it inside `ch` just like it does with the commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this if you like to keep the commas

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  stringstream ss;
  string st = "2,3,55,33,1124,34"; 
  std::string token;
  ss.str(st);

  while(getline(ss, token, ',')) {
    cout << token << endl;
  }    

  return 0;
}
```